# Building a List Recursively Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

This is a pretty simple problem, and hopefully it has a simple answer as well. I am trying to generate a list of numbers up to N. For example, for N = 3, the program would output [0,1,2].

My problem is that my code gives me [[0,1,2]]. I need the list to be only one list, not nested inside another.

Here is my code:

```
genNhelp2(N,N,L,L).
genNhelp2(N,C,L,R) :-
    C < N,
    append(L,C,Res),
    C1 is C + 1,
    genNhelp2(N,C1,Res,R).

genN(N,R) :- 
    genNhelp2(N,0,[],R).
```

I also tried this, with the same results:

```
genNhelp(N,N,[]).
genNhelp(N,C,[C|R]) :- 
    C < N,
    C1 is C + 1,
    genNhelp(N,C1,R).

genN(N,R) :-
    genNhelp(N,0,R).
```

This seems like an easy fix, but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, your code yields this result: `?- genN(5, L).
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] ;
false.`

Comment: Please paste your actual code.  The code you provided does not generate `[[0,1,2]]`; it returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mind changing your signature from genN/2 to genN/3, such that it will be more generic and simple?This way:

```
genN(X, X, [X]).

genN(From, To, [From|T]) :-
    From1 is From + 1,
    genN(From1, To, T).
```

Now to are able to do stuff like:

```
>> genN(0, 3, L).
L = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

and even

```
>> genN(-2, 4, L).
L = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Then he could simply add in `genN(N, L) :- genN(0, N, L).` :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the helper.  How about this?

```
genN(0,[]).
genN(N,R) :- 
   N > 0,
   N1 is N-1,
   genN(N1,R1),
   append(R1,[N1],R).
```

Comment: That still gives me the array that I am trying to avoid. Could it be a problem with my interpreter?

Comment: What interpreter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work:

```
gen_range(N,Ns) :-     % to generate a list of sequential numbers,
  gen_range(N,0,[],Ns) % - just invoke the helper, appropriately seeded
  .                    % - that's all there is to it.

gen_range(0,_,Ns,NS).        % succeed when the range is complete
gen_range(N,X,Ts,Ns) :-      % otherwise...
  N > 0 ,                    % - if the range is not yet complete
  N1 is N-1 ,                % - increment X
  X1 is X+1 ,                % - decrement N
  gen_range(N1,X1,[X|Ts],Ns) % - and recurse down.
  .                          %
```